# How to force vertical space in tex4ht? \bigskip and \vspace have no effect

Tags: spacing, tex4ht

I am generating lots of tables one after the other, and noticed the tables in HTML generated by tex4ht are touching each others, and wanted to have some vertical white space between them to separate them a little.

In PDF, I can use `\bigskip` or `\vspace{\baselineskip}` and these work with no problem, but they have no effect in the HTML page produces by tex4ht.

Is there a trick to tell tex4ht to please add some extra vertical space?  MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}% 
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}       

\begin{longtable}{|p{.5\textwidth}|}\hline
test
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\bigskip
\begin{longtable}{|p{.5\textwidth}|}\hline
test
\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The pdf is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the HTML is `make4ht foo.tex`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I probably can fix this using `.cfg` and add some CSS commands or such, but first I wanted to see if it is possible to do in all in LaTeX.

Looking the HTML generated, shows that the `\bigskip` is just ignored in HTML and has no effect.

TL 2015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to redefine `\bigskip` to produce empty paragraph with some height. The problem is that `\bigskip` etc. is used internally in some LaTeX commands and environments, so it could break quite a lot of configurations. It  is best to suppress it by default. I would use custom spacing commands instead.

```
% myspaces.sty 
\newcommand\mybigskip{\bigskip}
\newcommand\mymedskip{\medskip}
\newcommand\mysmallskip{\smallskip}
```

tex4ht configuration

```
% myspaces.4ht
\newcommand\:myskip[1]{\ifvmode\HCode{<span class="#1">}\:nbsp\HCode{</span>}\fi}
\renewcommand\mybigskip{\:myskip{bigskip}}
\renewcommand\mymedskip{\:myskip{medskip}}
\renewcommand\mysmallskip{\:myskip{smallskip}}
\Css{span.bigskip{height:2em;margin:0;}}
\Css{span.medskip{height:1em;margin:0;}}
\Css{span.smallskip{height:0.5em;margin:0;}}
```

modified TeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}% 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{myspaces}
\begin{document}       

\begin{longtable}{|p{.5\textwidth}|}\hline
test
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\mybigskip
\begin{longtable}{|p{.5\textwidth}|}\hline
test
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\mymedskip
hello

\mysmallskip
world
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea but the space generated seems to be the same as ~ (i.e. paragraph) for all settings.  i.e. changing the values of heights has no effect. It seems that just emitting a span there causing the space to be generated, period, which is the same amount of space one gets using nbsp. I also think you'd need to make it `display: inline-block;` to change the margin, but I am no CSS expert by any means :) ps. I think there is a typo there, in the smallskip. `0:5em`? I changed it to `0.5em` which I think what you meant there.

Comment: @Nasser you are right, it should be `inline-block`. the constant space is caused by paragraph margins

Comment: Yes, that worked! thanks for both answers given. Both are good answers.

Comment: Is the above a typo? `height:0:5em;`  should this be `height:0.5em;` ? I've been using `\mysmallskip` to add vertical space before and after enumeration list, but the space comes out way too large and can't figure how to reduce it. Not sure what to do. But thought to check with you first if the syntax above is correct or not. I tried `height:0:1em;` and it had no effect on the vertical spacing.  I will try to make new question and MWE if you want.

Comment: @Nasser yes, it is a typo, it should be `height:0.5em;`

Comment: Thanks. But you wrote `height:0,5em` (with comma not period) in your updated post above. Do comma and period work the same in HTML? I need to try to find out.

Comment: @Nasser ah, my bad, of course it should be a period, not comma

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a paragraph containing a blank space `~` which will be converted to the equivalent of `&nbsp;`.

PDF:

[image]

HTML:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}       

\begin{longtable}{|p{.5\textwidth}|}
  \hline
  test \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

~

\begin{longtable}{|p{.5\textwidth}|}
  \hline
  test \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```